# jquery ajax post form function not submitting on timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this function which posts forms:

```
function post_form(form_id, type, redir_url) {
    $( form_id ).submit(function(e) {
        CheckRequired(e);
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        LoadModalBody('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>', 'Loading');
        $.ajax({
            url : '/section' + formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert(type);
                if(type === 'modal') {
                    if(redir_url === '') {
                        LoadModal('/section' + formURL, '');
                    } else {
                        LoadModal('/section' + redir_url, '');
                    }
                } else if(type === 'reload') {
                    if(redir_url === '') {
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                } else {
                    //close the loading modal
                    CloseModal();
                    //location.reload();
                    //$("body").html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //if fails
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

which works fine calling it like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/users/mileage" id="form1" onsubmit="post_form('#form1', 'modal');">

<input="submit" />
</form>
```

i am trying to use this code:

```
<form id="invoices" action="/accounting/dashboard" method="post">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeoutId;
    $('#invoices input, #invoices textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {    
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change   
            //saveToDB();
            post_form('#invoices', '', '');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

but its just not posting and there are no errors showing in the console

all other forms using the `onSubmit` in the form tag work fine but i just cannot get it to post on timeout using the above jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the submit handler `$( form_id ).submit(function(e)` it is unnecessary in both of your usage cases.

In the first case you trigger off the inline `onsubmit="postform(...)"`.

It doesn't work in the second case because you don't trigger a submit event.

**Edit for a clearer example**

If you want to move the AJAX call so it triggers off the input change...

Let's remove the `onsubmit` from the form element.

```
<form id="invoices" action="/accounting/dashboard" method="post">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Set up a submit handler so the browser won't do the normal form submission which could cause your page to navigate away.

```
$("#invoices").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    postForm("#invoices");
});
```

Handle the property change event

```
var timeoutId;
$("#invoices input").on("input propertychange change", function() {
   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
   timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
       postForm("#invoices");
   }, 1000); 
});
```

Do the AJAX post

```
function postForm(formId) {
    var form = $(formId);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, error) { }
    });
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLkh8an0/) example.

**What's different?**

In the second case you've wrapped the AJAX request in a form submission event. But it will never trigger because you are in the change event. I suggested you remove the submit handler because you are essentially setting up a submit handler within the inline `onsubmit`.

1. You trigger a change event
2. You call `post_form()` which *sets up* a submission handler
3. Done. Submit was not triggered.

Comment: Ok I'll change that for the first one that's already working. How do I get the second one to works

Comment: i just tried and i need to keep the `$( form_id ).submit(function(e)` because otherwise it doesn't submit

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that in your code you have on "propertychange change".

If you want on click than you have to do the following:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){ "your code"});
```